# Cannot publish new release to Google Play because of Sensitive app permissions

Tags: android, permissions, expo

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot create any new releases on any of the Google Play release tracks (internal, alpha, beta, production) since one of the old releases required location permissons.

Upon saving the new draft release using an app bundle without these permissions I can continue to the next screen to review the settings, but I cannot proceed to roll-out the release because there is an error due to old releases not being compliant. It seems strange to me that I cannot roll-out a new version because of problems with an older version.

[image]

Basically I can start the survey, but that's the only thing I can do. However, since I'm not using background location access in any of my new builds I just would like to skip this and replace the old release with new releases without sensitive permissions.

[image]

Trying to submit the app bundle through the Expo command-line interface using `expo upload:android` also fails. The error message reveals very little details.

```
[logs] [17:39:05]: Updating track 'internal'...
[logs] [17:39:06]: Uploading all changes to Google Play...
[logs] [!] Google Api Error: Server error - Internal error encountered.
[logs] fastlane supply failed
[logs] Failed to submit the app
```

I also tried contacting Google, but this didn't help so far. Neither did filling out the form explaining the situation.

Comment: Did you find a solution...? We are also facing the same problem.

Comment: @JoelB I ended up closing down the app and submitting a new one using a slightly different package name. I hope Google improves this because it is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by uploading a build and ensured that it's Permissions didn't request Location permissions. I then filled out the declaration pointing out the App didn't use Location permissions.

I also uploaded a YouTube video pointing this out also.

My App was reviewed and then a few days later was approved.